# Find earliest and latest timestamp per day, created calculated column with time in between

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm fairly new to DAX & PowerBI and I'm trying to wrap my head around how I can determine and calculate timeframes per day.

The Goal:

- Get the minimum and maximum timestamps for each day in the data set
- Calculate the time difference between the two in HH:MM
- Created a calculated column to store the HH:MM result

So far I have found the following two DAX queries to work when creating a calculated column of the min and max timestamps:

```
CALCULATE(MIN('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines'[Timestamp]),FILTER('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines',FORMAT([Timestamp],"DD-MM-YYYY")=FORMAT(EARLIER([Timestamp]),"DD-MM-YYYY")))

CALCULATE(MAX('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines'[Timestamp]),FILTER('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines',FORMAT([Timestamp],"DD-MM-YYYY")=FORMAT(EARLIER([Timestamp]),"DD-MM-YYYY")))
```

However I am having a hard time trying to calculate and store the difference between the two results. I do not seem to be able to call the calculated columns when creating a new column to calculate, and when I have tried to combine them into the same column creation, the results are far from accurate.

```
Column = 
VAR firstscan =
    CALCULATE(MIN('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines'[Timestamp]),FILTER('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines',FORMAT([Timestamp],"DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM")=FORMAT(EARLIER([Timestamp]),"DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM")))
VAR lastscan =
    CALCULATE(MAX('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines'[Timestamp]),FILTER('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines',FORMAT([Timestamp],"DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM")=FORMAT(EARLIER([Timestamp]),"DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM")))

RETURN
    CALCULATE(lastscan - firstscan)
```

I have tried with and without and `HH:MM` and the result still shows me in 1899 for every line. Any advice or pointers would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution to this issue via the following;

Created a calculated table, which created a date and email for every distinct user, within the specified time range.

```
hoursWorked = 
GENERATE(CALENDAR(DATE(2020, 1, 1), DATE(2030, 12, 31)),  SUMMARIZE('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines', 'Packing Jobs - Pick Lines'[Email]))
```

Created two calculated columns, one to get the first timestamp of the day for each user, and one for the last timestamp each day.

```
startTime = 
CALCULATE (
    MIN('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines'[Timestamp]),
    FILTER(
            'Packing Jobs - Pick Lines',
            'Packing Jobs - Pick Lines'[Email] = hoursWorked[Email] && FORMAT(hoursWorked[Date], "DD-MM-YYYY") = FORMAT('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines'[Timestamp], "DD-MM-YYYY")
        )
)

endTime = 
CALCULATE (
    MAX('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines'[Timestamp]),
    FILTER(
            'Packing Jobs - Pick Lines',
            'Packing Jobs - Pick Lines'[Email] = hoursWorked[Email] && FORMAT(hoursWorked[Date], "DD-MM-YYYY") = FORMAT('Packing Jobs - Pick Lines'[Timestamp], "DD-MM-YYYY")
        )
)
```

Finally I calculated a minute value for every day the user has timestamps, storing them all in a final calculated column called minutes.

```
minutes = 
DATEDIFF(hoursWorked[startTime], hoursWorked[endTime], MINUTE)
```

To map this with the data in `'Packing Jobs - Pick Lines'` I created a relationship between the `email` field in both tables.

Hope this helps anyone else who may encounter the same issue!